# Has Wyatt Earp ever been a character basis for science fiction?

Tags: movie, novel, character-development

I'm not looking for the archetype "Old West Lawman". I'm looking for specific instances where Wyatt Earp was the Prime character influence.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gunfighters

Answer (score 4):

Mike Resnick's [The Buntline Special](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C4B2LGO) is a steampunk novel that features Earp as one of the main protagonists, along with Doc Holliday.

Answer (score 3):

In the [Star Trek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek%3a_The_Original_Series) episode "Spectre of the Gun", several members of the Enterprise crew were placed into a simulation of Tombstone Arizona which ended in the legendary gunfight, though without the original outcome.